# How can I set up an URL rewrite filter BEFORE authentication in Spring 5?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

We have a working Spring 4 multi-tenant web application under development, which has the Tuckey UrlRewriter filter in the beginning of the filter chain (before authentication, session management, etc).

Our URLs looks like this: `http://example.com/mytenant/content`
Which is rewritten to: `http://example.com/content?_s=mytenant`

Until now, all filters (authentication, session) were triggered for both rewritten and non-rewritten URLs (because in Spring 4 all filters were configured for both `DispatcherType.REQUEST` and `DispatcherType.FORWARD` by default)

Now, we are trying out Spring 5, and now (following the servlet specification) the filters are not being triggered after the rewrite event.

I guess reconfiguring all filters for `DispatcherType.FORWARD` too, would be a solution, but it seems ugly (I guess there is a good reason for the new defaults), so I am still searching for a better solution. What would be a recommended way for this in Spring 5? (maybe I use the UrlRewrite filter completely wrong)

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Was this ever figured out?

Comment: Hi! We choose a different, simpler approach. In the final solution we didn't touch any of the configuration mentioned above. Instead we created a new filter (TenantFilter), which run before the url rewrite. This filter puts the tenant's name into ThreadLocal instead of an url parameter.

We are Spring beginners, so I'm not sure this is a good solution or not, but it's working for now in our environment.